# perlbrew fails with "Can't locate Devel/PatchPerl.pm"

Tags: perl, perlbrew

`perlbrew` fails with `Can't locate Devel/PatchPerl.pm`.

More precisely, what fails is a run of `patchperl` that is spawned off by `perlbrew`.

There *is* in fact a `Devel/PatchPerl.pm` accessible via the paths in the environment variable `PERL5LIB`, but `perlbrew` unconditionally *deletes* this variable before it runs `perlpatch`:

```
delete $ENV{$_} for qw(PERL5LIB PERL5OPT);
```

I can't find anything in the `perlbrew` documentation justifying this maneuver.

Can someone explain why `perlbrew` does this?

EDIT:

Below is a `bash` script that reproduces the problem.  I run it like this (with some suitable `<PATH_TO_SCRIPT>`):

```
% env -i HOME=$HOME SHELL=/bin/bash /bin/bash --noprofile --norc
bash-3.2$ /bin/bash --norc --noprofile <PATH_TO_SCRIPT>
```

The script's running time is about 4 minutes on my machine.  The last few lines of output, including the lines showing the error are below:

```
(cd /tmp/perlbrew_root/build/perl-5.16.3 && rm -f config.sh Policy.sh && patchperl && sh Configure -de '-Dprefix=/tmp/perlbrew_root/perls/perl-5.16.3' '-A'eval:scriptdir=/tmp/perlbrew_root/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin'' && make  && make test_harness && make install) 2>&1 | tee /tmp/perlbrew_root/build.perl-5.16.3.log
Can't locate Devel/PatchPerl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at /tmp/testperl/bin/patchperl line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /tmp/testperl/bin/patchperl line 12.
perl-5.16.3 is successfully installed.
```

The last line of the output above (`perl-5.16.3 is successfully installed.`) is nonsense: a real build and installation of `perl-5.16.3` would take roughly one order of magnitude longer than this script's running time, which, as already stated, is about 4 minutes on my machine.

Note the `@INC` in the error.  I don't see how `patchperl` could possibly find `Devel/PatchPerl.pm`, which is under `/tmp/testperl/lib/perl5`, given that `@INC`.

```
PERLDIR=/tmp/testperl
/bin/rm -rf "$PERLDIR"

/bin/rm -rf /tmp/build
/bin/mkdir -p /tmp/build
cd /tmp/build

/usr/bin/curl -s http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AP/APEIRON/local-lib-1.008009.tar.gz | tar xzf -

pushd local-lib-1.008009
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL "--bootstrap=$PERLDIR"
  /usr/bin/make install
popd

eval "$( /usr/bin/perl -I$PERLDIR/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$PERLDIR )"

/usr/bin/cpan App::cpanminus

export PERLBREW_ROOT=/tmp/perlbrew_root
export PERLBREW_HOME=/tmp/perlbrew_home
/bin/rm -rf "$PERLBREW_ROOT" "$PERLBREW_HOME"

$PERLDIR/bin/cpanm App::perlbrew
$PERLDIR/bin/perlbrew init
source "$PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc"

$PERLDIR/bin/perlbrew install -v perl-5.16.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade perlbrew (`perlbrew self-upgrade` or the shell bootstrap incantation from http://perlbrew.pl/).

Recent versions install patchperl into `$PERLBREW_ROOT/bin` through `perlbrew install-patchperl`.

Comment: `perlbrew self-upgrade` returns `Your perlbrew is up-to-date.`

Comment: @kjo then try `perlbrew install-patchperl`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this after trying a fresh (only) install of perlbrew, after installing `local::lib`. When installing perlbrew via CPAN (not the only way, I've used `curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash` before, with `local::lib` disabled), the `Devel::PatchPerl` module was properly installed into `~/perl5/lib/perl5`, but as we both found out, `perlbrew` won't look there. Running **`perlbrew install-patchperl`** installs a standalone version of patchperl — built with `App::FatPacker` — into `~/perl5/perlbrew/bin`.

This allows me to have a local "system" perl, with customized libraries and tools provided by `local::lib`, for ordinary and experimental work. But I can switch to using a `perlbrew`'ed perl for special projects or applications, for an even more controlled environment. The real system perl is almost never modified.

**Caveat** - when local::lib is enabled by default in your `.bashrc`, a simple `perlbrew use perl-5.18.2` does NOT remove the `local:lib`-specific environment varialbles (PERL_MM_OPT and PERL_MM_OPT - you must do it yourself. One (somewhat cumbersome, but simple) trick is:

```
perlbrew lib create perl-5.18.2@none  # do this once after brewing a perl
perlbrew use perl-5.18.2@none
perlbrew use perl-5.18.2
```

This also means, that to switch off perlbrew, you can do this:

```
perlbrew off
eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib | grep -v PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT)
```

And you are back to your default local::lib setup. Though better to close and reopen a new shell, to avoid extending your `$PATH` ad infinitum.

This is the simplest way I have found so far to get independent, custom  perl environments, including the system perl with your default (local::lib) customizations.

Answer (score -1):

> Can someone explain why `perlbrew` does this?

Devel::PatchPerl is found inside of `patchperl`. `perlbrew` surely clears those vars so you don't accidentally find the wrong modules (as it would have for you if `perlbrew` hadn't cleared those).

Something wrong if your install of `perlbrew` if `patchperl` can't find code that's suppose to be present in `patchperl` itself! Reinstall it from scratch.

Comment: In the process of debugging this I've reinstalled `perlbrew` from scratch so many times I've lost count...  I don't understand what you mean by "Devel::PatchPerl is found inside of `patchperl`".  My fresh-installed copy is under `$LOCALPERL/lib/perl5`.  See the latest `EDIT` in my post.

Comment: It's literally in the file `patchperl`.