# How to install perlbrew without root access?

Tags: perl, include, perlbrew

How do you install `perlbrew` without root access?

Part way through the installation process I am getting `Can't locate Devel/PatchPerl.pm in @INC` in the installation log when it fails.

Comment: http://weblog.bulknews.net/post/58079418600/plenv-alternative-for-perlbrew worthy replacement for perlbrew.

Answer (score 4):

It's a known issue. See [perlbrew fails with "Can't locate Devel/PatchPerl.pm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113467/perlbrew-fails-with-cant-locate-devel-patchperl-pm)

Try installing the latest version

```
\curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

Refer: https://perlbrew.pl/

Comment: I have just started installing it today so I am using the latest version already.  Did you think I had an old copy of the script and files lying around?